# Import OSM map and reverse geocode to town/city

Tags: neo4j, openstreetmap, cypher, reverse-geocoding, neo4j-spatial

I'm pretty new to neo4j and the spatial plugin for it so bear with me.

I've used the OSM importer to import the whole of Ireland into the db and now I'm able to query it with the rest API to find nodes within X km of a point. *(side note: I am unable to get the Cypher query to return any results? Does the OSMImporter add the data to an index for querying or must I loop through it all and add to an index myself now?)*

What I actually want is a rudimental reverse geocoder style query. I want to query the graph for the geometry that contains a geo coordinate, check if this is a town/city/village etc, if not check its ancestors until it is able to tell me what town/county/state I am inside.

Unfortunately I'm quite lost and I've tried, unsuccessfully, looking through the neo4j-spatial code and examples for a start point.